# Better way to make init a java builder class from clojure map?

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

everyone

I'm try to write a function to wrap [CsvReadOptions.Builder.html](http://static.javadoc.io/tech.tablesaw/tablesaw-core/0.25.2/tech/tablesaw/io/csv/CsvReadOptions.Builder.html) in clojure .

The function will take a map like this : {:header true :locale "US"}, the function will configure the builder according to the map.

```
(defn reader-options [ opts ]
  (let [ b (CsvReadOptions$Builder.)]
    (cond-> b
      (contains? opts :locale ) (.locale (:locale opts))
      (contains? opts :header ) (.header (:header opts))
        true (.build ))
  )
)
```

Sorry if it is too much to ask, is there a better way in clojure to accomplish this ? because the key works duplicates in single line.

```
      (contains? opts :locale ) (.locale (:locale opts))
```

Thank you again for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you can write a macro that expands into the code you need:

```
(defmacro defbuilder [fn-name builder-class fields]
  (let [opts (gensym)]
    `(defn ~fn-name [~opts]
       (cond-> (new ~builder-class)
         ~@(mapcat
            (fn [field-sym]
              (let [field-kw (keyword (name field-sym))]
                `((contains? ~opts ~field-kw)
                  (. ~field-sym (get ~opts ~field-kw)))))
            fields)
         true (.build)))))
```

Now,

```
(defbuilder options-from-map CsvReadOptions$Builder
  [header locale...])
```

will generate:

```
(clojure.core/defn options-from-map [G__12809]
  (clojure.core/cond-> (new CsvReadOptions$Builder)
    (clojure.core/contains? G__12809 :header)
    (. header (clojure.core/get G__12809 :header))
    (clojure.core/contains? G__12809 :locale)
    (. locale (clojure.core/get G__12809 :locale))
    ...
    true (.build)))
```

In practice, however, this code is:

- less readable and less maintainable (there are libraries that heavily use macros and they are a pain to read), and
- you may want to add additional specific processing for some methods (for example, converting a locale string to a `Locale` object).

Thus, you are much better off writing a wrapper by hand - or, if you need to use a Builder just once in your code, omit the wrapper altogether and use interop.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring) in `let`:

```
(let [{:keys [a b c]} {:a 1 :b false}]
  [a b c])
;; => [1 false nil]
```

or in function arguments:

```
(defn args-demo [{:keys [a b c]}]
  [a b c])
(args-demo {:a 1 :b false})
;; => [1 false nil]
```

The issue is that it binds to `nil` if a specific key is not present in the map. If your values can have `nil` values then it won't work.

You could use some "marker" values for not present values:

```
(let [{:keys [a b c] :or {a ::absent b ::absent c ::absent}} {:a 1 :b nil}]
  (cond-> {}
    (not= a ::absent) (assoc :a2 a)
    (not= b ::absent) (assoc :b2 b)
    (not= c ::absent) (assoc :c2 c)))
;; => {:a2 1, :b2 nil}
```

You could also create a macro:

```
(defmacro when-key-present
  [k m & body]
  `(let [{:keys [~k] :or {~k ::not-found}} ~m]
     (when (not= ~k ::not-found)
       ~@body)))

(when-key-present a {:a false :b nil}
  (println "a was" a))
;; prints "a was false"

(when-key-present b {:a false :b nil}
  (println "b was" b))
;; prints "b was nil"

(when-key-present c {:a false :b nil}
  (println "c was" c))
;; doesn't print anything
```

And your function would become:

```
(defn reader-options [opts]
  (let [builder (CsvReadOptions$Builder.)]
    (when-key-present locale opts
      (.locale builder locale))
    (when-key-present header opts
      (.header builder header))
    (.build builder)))
```

You could go even beyond and create a macro that would assume that the key in opts map is identical to the builder method that should be invoked so you could then use it like:

```
(let [builder (CsvReadOptions$Builder.)]
  (doseq [k (keys opts)]
    (set-builder-property builder k opts)))
```

but this becomes more and more magical and harder to understand so I would think twice before resorting to macros.

Answer (score 0):

In this problem you have several factors present:

1. Optional parameters
2. Mutable objects
3. Java interop

This is the reason you are getting `locale` and `header` replicated 3 times on each line.  I cannot think of a straightforward way of reducing this duplication.  If this was a common pattern in you application, you could write a macro (compiler extension) to make it easier.  Unless this is a very frequent occurrance in your code, the cost (in complexity, documentation, misunderstandings, etc) is going to greatly exceed the benefit.

Kind of like buying a new car instead of cleaning the old car.  Except in extreme circumstances, the cost is probably not worth the benefit.

;)